# Finding iPad games that can be played over the internet

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, internet, games

What is the best way to find new iPad games that can be played over the internet? (Not splitscreen, not bluetooth, not WiFi, only the ones that can be played over larger distances)

(I know there are a lot of game review sites out there, but none of them seems to have the filter options I need.) The answer could be a set of search terms I could use, or a review site, but I'm looking for a source to find these games.

Comment: see http://www.maclife.com/article/gallery/10_great_game_center_multiplayer_apps

Comment: Are you looking for shared reality games or simulation / head to head or turn based games? There are quite a few that come to mind. (or did I misinterpret the question and you really want to know systems for finding them like review sites, circles of friends or magazines with paid staff to independently review apps to avoid paid marketing efforts?

Comment: Go into GameCenter.  It lists games.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Game Center.

Select the Games section.

You will see the "Find More Games" button there.

Or open App Store>Games>Game Center to see a list of Internet based multiplayer games.

Comment: Game Center integration doesn't mean online multiplayer. The app could use Game Center just for single player leaderboards.